# Adadfruit Trinket software not running on ATtiny85

Tags: adafruit, nrf24l01+, attiny85

I have an application that uses a pair of nRF24L01+ as a simple RF link between a camera PC sync output and a set of LED flashes. The important factors are power and low latency - hence the 2.4GHz.

I developed both ends using UNOs and then moved to Trinket 3 V. The system works very well with Trinkets.
My next step was to strip this down further to ATtiny85 at least at the receiver end.
I overcame the programming challenges and a day's worth of board installation in Arduino IDE and can <strike>not</strike> now program the ATtiny85 as well as the Trinket.

I will share the code lower down, but let me explain the difference in result.

With the Trinket the trigger output from the receiver is a simple pulse the width of the transmitted pulse (as is the goal.

```
               __________________________________
 _____________|                                  |__________________________
```

The pulse is anywhere from 5 ms to 50 ms.

On the ATtiny85 the link is clearly operational from transmitter to receiver but the output is ugly. Something like this:

```
                 _____      _____            _____
________________|     |____|     |__________|     |___________
```

The pulses appear (not always the same number) for the duration of the transmitted pulse and the interval is variable. The pulses themselves are of 8 MHz duration.

**The code:**

```cpp
#include "RF24.h"

// Note: these includes looked necessary when I started but during debugging I
// removed them with not change in functionality - strange!
//#include <Mirf85.h>
//#include <MirfHardwareSpiDriver85.h>
//#include <MirfSpiDriver85.h>
//#include <nRF24L0185.h>
//#include <SPI85.h>

/*    **ATtiny25/45/85 Pin map with CE_PIN 3 and CSN_PIN 4**
      nRF24L01 CE oins is tied high and pin3 is used as the trigger output.

                                   +-\/-+
                     NC      PB5  1|o   |8  Vcc --- nRF24L01  VCC, pin2 --- LED --- 5V
      nRF24L01  CE, pin3 --- PB3  2|    |7  PB2 --- nRF24L01  SCK, pin5
      nRF24L01 CSN, pin4 --- PB4  3|    |6  PB1 --- nRF24L01 MOSI, pin6
      nRF24L01 GND, pin1 --- GND  4|    |5  PB0 --- nRF24L01 MISO, pin7
                                   +----+
*/
*    **Trinket 3V Pin map with CE_PIN 3 and CSN_PIN 4 **
* @code
*                                 + -\ / - +
*                   NC      PB5  1 | o   | 8  Vcc -- - nRF24L01  VCC, pin2 -- - LED -- - 5V
*    nRF24L01  CE, pin3 -- - PB3  2 |    | 7  PB2 -- - nRF24L01  SCK, pin5
*    nRF24L01 CSN, pin4 -- - PB4  3 |    | 6  PB1 -- - nRF24L01 MOSI, pin6
*    nRF24L01 GND, pin1 -- - GND  4 |    | 5  PB0 -- - nRF24L01 MISO, pin7
*                                 +---- +


// (Create an instance of a radio, specifying the CE and CS pins. )
RF24 myRadio (3, 4); // "myRadio" is the identifier you will use in following methods
/*-----( Declare Variables )-----*/
byte addresses[][6] = {"1Node"}; // Create address for 1 pipe.
int dataReceived;  // Data that will be received from the transmitter
int flashPin = 3;
int flashValue = 0;
long flashStartMicros = micros();

void setup()
{
  pinMode (flashPin, OUTPUT);

  myRadio.begin();  // Start up the physical nRF24L01 Radio
  myRadio.setChannel(108);  // Above most Wifi Channels
  // Set the PA Level low to prevent power supply related issues since this is a
  // getting_started sketch, and the likelihood of close proximity of the devices. RF24_PA_MAX is default.
  myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  //  myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);  // Uncomment for more power

  myRadio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[0]); // Use the first entry in array 'addresses' (Only 1 right now)
  myRadio.startListening();

  digitalWrite(flashPin, 0);
}//--(end setup )---


void loop()
{
  if ( myRadio.available()) // Check for incoming data from transmitter
  {
    flashStartMicros = micros();
    while (myRadio.available())  // While there is data ready
    {
      myRadio.read( &dataReceived, sizeof(dataReceived) ); // Get the data payload (You must have defined that already!)
    }
    if (dataReceived == 8) {
      flashValue = 1;
      digitalWrite(flashPin, flashValue);
    }
  }
  if ( micros() - flashStartMicros > 1500) {
    flashValue = 0;
    digitalWrite(flashPin, flashValue);
  } //END Radio available
}//--(end main loop )---
```

Simply - I send a character, received it and set trigger high. Then time out and set it low. There is only one statement setting pin 3 (`flashPin`) low.

I have spent 2 days trying to find the difference.

Comment: The flash pin is the same as the CE pin?

Comment: CE pin is tied high to Vcc and Flash in is set to output. This works on the Trinket.

Comment: change the last `digitalWrite(flashPin, flashValue);` to `digitalWrite(flashPin, 1);` .... that will tell you if the output is going low because of that line

Comment: I changed the line as you suggested and the LED comes on (the pin goes high) and stays on. I put a delay at the end of the setup() to see when it gets set high and it waited low for the delay then went high. It does not react to the pulse of course. Fair suggestion though.

Comment: since you posted a waveform, I assume that you have a scope of some kind. .... check all the other pins of the nRF24L01+ .... see if there is a difference between the Trinket and the ATtiny85 ..... could it be the power supply voltage? ... or maybe something to do with the CE pin

Comment: I have and I should do that. Thanks for the suggestions. I'll get to that in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

My debugging effort was in an endless DO loop because I was trying to see why the ATtiny was not acting on the received data like the Trinket. Thanks to some simple questions from #jsotola I looked at what the Trinket signals looked like to compare.
Turns out, my transmitted was broken and that both receivers were dealing with the same garbage. Now I do not have a difference between the 2 receivers and I can go back and make the TX do what I need it to do. 
“When you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.”